# How do I change permanently the encoding of a text file?

Tags: character-encoding

I have a bunch of html files encoded as iso-8859-1-unix and a few encoded in utf-8-unix. What I want is to encode all of them in utf-8-unix.
I have already tried (I think they are the same command, actually):

```
C-x C-m f utf-8-unix
C-x RET f utf-8-unix
```

the modeline changes from 1 to U, but after I close the file and reopen it, the modeline shows 1 again. It seems that I cannot make the change permanent no matter what I try and I don't understand why.

Following the suggestions below, I have created a new file with this content

```
<ul class="navbar">
  <li><a href="index.php">home</a></li>
  <li><a href="bio.php">bio</a></li>
  <li><a href="research.php">research</a></li>
  <li><a href="software.php">software</a></li>
  <li><a href="contacts.php">contacts</a></li>
</ul>
```

`C-h v buffer-file-coding-system` returns this:

```
Its value is utf-8-unix
Local in buffer new.htm; global value is the same.
```

so it looks okay. I save, kill the buffer, reopen the file and `C-h v buffer-file-coding-system` returns this:

```
Its value is undecided-unix
Local in buffer new.htm; global value is utf-8-unix
```

I am really confused.

EDIT: thanks everybody for helping making this clear!

Comment: Are you saving the file after changing the encoding?

Comment: @JordonBiondo yes I am.

Comment: The standard way to permanently set the coding is to [add it as a file local variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables): `M-x add-file-local-variable RET coding RET utf-8 RET`, save, and you're done.  But we should know the content of the file to understand why Emacs keeps opening it with iso-8859-1 coding.

Comment: @giordano how do I check the current value of the file local variable? the content of the file is nothing special, just some standard html.

Comment: `C-h v coding RET` you must issue this command in that buffer.  Maybe there is a special character forcing Emacs think the file has in a particular coding.  Or maybe you have something in your init file.

Comment: @giordano odd. if I do `C-h v coding` and press RET I get prompted to select a completion among: `coding-category-*`, `coding-system-*`, etc.. but it does not look like there is avariable called just `coding`

Comment: Sorry, my fault, see `buffer-file-coding-system` variable

Comment: The example you gave in the question contains only ASCII characters. So its UTF-8 encoding and Latin-1 encoding will be identical. In particular, there is no way for emacs to tell the encodings apart when you open the file. Anyhow, if the `<head>` section of your HTML file contains `<meta charset='utf-8'>`, then html-mode should use that to decide the encoding when you open the file. No need to use file local variables in this case.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I see. So if the file only contains ASCII characters it does not make a difference if I set the encoding to latin-1, utf8 or leave undecided. whatever I put in `meta charset` will be the file encoding?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am saying.

Comment: The function `prefer-coding-system` might be of help, but this is a global preference, not file specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**N.B.**: Question answered in comments.